# Jinja2 - how to assign value to a variable based on if else condition?

Tags: jinja2

I want to do something really simple in Jinja2 - `if a>100 then do nothing else let b = 5`. Here's my attempt but it does not work:

```
{% if a|float>100 %}
{% else %}
{% set b=5 %}
{% endif %}
```

I got an error like this:

*jinja2.exceptions.TemplatesyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '%'*

I couldn't find the correct syntax from Jinja2 documentation, so please kindly help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If nothing happens if the first condition is true, why don't you go straight to the second one?

How about:

```
{% if ( a|float>100 ) == false %}
    {% set b=5 %}
{% endif %}`
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhia. Your idea is good but my question is more about the syntax - I am not sure if why my codes got a syntax error. Do you think it's because of the indentation on the line of  `set` ?